# Лог изменения кода функций/процедур PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Хочу попробовать написать тригер, который будет сохранять в таблицу код процедуры/функции и автора изменения с временной меткой.

1. Судя по документации постгерса, тригер на событие "create or replace [объект]" невозможен. Подскажите, это можно как-то обойти? (я предполагаю, что изменение кода объекта должно сопровождаться его вставкой в какую-то системную таблицу - вероятно, можно на этом сыграть)
2. Подскажите, как можно реализовать "снепшот кода"? Опять же, вероятно есть какая-то системная таблица, хранящая нужную мне информацию?

P.S. Нагуглить готовое решение не смог, если вдруг сталкивались и поделитесь ссылкой - буду благодарен.

P.S.S. На проекте Greenplum, следовательно вопрос актуально для Postgres'a

Comment: По-моему, вам следует смотреть в сторону инструментов контроля версий баз данных, таких как Liquibase, Flyway и пр.

Comment: См. [pg_proc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html) и [Information Schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html), [information_schema.routines](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-routines.html)

Comment: Попытался воссоздать решение "Триггерная процедура для аудита" из документации https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/plpgsql-trigger , но споткнулся на том, что pg_proc - это сис. каталог, а не таблица, и тригер на него не повесить

Comment: Случайно попалась на глаза статья с информацией по указанному вопросу. Прочитать пока не успел, но оставлю её здесь - https://info-comp.ru/postgresql-ddl-log